# Aligning two linear referenced datasets with Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm looking to align and combine multiple different datasets that are linearly referenced.

For example, say I have two different datasets that are linear referenced. Linear referenced (to me) means that the dataset references a long (linear) asset (e.g. a road, railway, pipeline, etc.) and contains attributes that point to a specific section of that linear asset, defined typically in a 2d space with a begin and an end.

For example, take these two tables (DataFrames [pandas]):

| Start | End | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | Blue |
| 2 | 4 | Red |
| 4 | 6 | Green |

And

| Start | End | Material |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | Wood |
| 3 | 6 | Concrete |

The end result of what I'm looking for would look like this:

| Start | End | Colour | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | Blue | Wood |
| 2 | 3 | Red | Wood |
| 3 | 4 | Red | Concrete |
| 4 | 6 | Green | Concrete |

I'm struggling to think of or find a method that does this without heavy looping and condition statements. How is the best way to go about this? Are there any libraries that do a good job of managed linear referenced datasets?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.